# In Ruby how to retrieve only the keys from a hash that has both hashes and arrays and array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

```
{
    "CourseID": 1111,
    "Course": {
        "Code": "ABCD",
        "Name": "ABCD",
        "Qualification": "ABCD",
        "Discipline": "ABCD"
    },
    "Modules": [
        {
            "ID": 12345,
            "Code": "ABCD",
            "Name": "ABCD",
            "Core": true,
            "Units": [
                {
                    "ID": 23456,
                    "Code": "ABCD",
                    "Name": "ABCD",
                    "Core": true,
                    "my_key": true
                },
                {
                    "ID": 34567,
                    "Code": "ABCD",
                    "Name": "ABCD",
                    "Core": true,
                    "my_key": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The values above are all different and I don't really care about the values.

So what I need from above is

[CourseID, Course, Code, Name, Qualification, Discipline, Modules, ID, Code, Name, Core, Units, ID, Code, Name, Core, my_key, ID, Code, Name, Core, my_key]

The above array has repetitions and I want that.

I have been breaking my head with it for a few hours and just can't get it.

```
something.each do |key, value|
  hash = {key => value}
  hash.map { |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      v.map { |x, y|
        hash = x
      }
    elsif v.is_a?(Array)
      v.map { |x, y|
        x.select { |k, v|
          hash1 = [k].include? k
        }
      }
    end
  }
end
```

If someone can help me with this, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have neither a valid Ruby data structure nor a valid JSON string.

Comment: @CodeGnome - I had some formatting issues.I just reformated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'json'

# Decode a JSON string into a Ruby object
h = JSON.parse <<END
  # Your JSON structure here
END

# Will return all hash keys of o
def keys(o)
  # If it is an array, returns the keys of each element
  return o.map {|e| keys(e) }.flatten(1) if Array === o
  # If it is an hash, returns the keys and the keys of each value
  return o.map {|k, v| [k, *keys(v)] }.flatten(1) if Hash === o
  # Otherwise, it has no keys. Return an empty array
  []
end

keys(h) # Calls the method just defined
# => ["CourseID", "Course", "Code", "Name", "Qualification", "Discipline",
#     "Modules", "ID", "Code", "Name", "Core", "Units", "ID", "Code", "Name",
#     "Core", "my_key", "ID", "Code", "Name", "Core", "my_key"]
```

Comment: Nice solution! Very compact. I have to remember that! The resulting array seems to be not in the order desired by OP, though?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal - awesome. That worked perfectly for me. can you give me a little explanation as to how 'o' actually receives the json.?

Comment: and what is the keys method..?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, but I added some explanations to the answer. Is it cleaner now?

Answer (score 0):

```
  x = {
    CourseID: 1111,
    Course: {
        Code: "ABCD",
        Name: "ABCD",
        Qualification: "ABCD",
        Discipline: "ABCD"
    },
    Modules: [
        {
            ID: 12345,
            Code: "ABCD",
            Name: "ABCD",
            Core: true,
            Units: [
                {
                    ID: 23456,
                    Code: "ABCD",
                    Name: "ABCD",
                    Core: true,
                    my_key: true
                },
                {
                    ID: 34567,
                    Code: "ABCD",
                    Name: "ABCD",
                    Core: true,
                    my_key: true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

def keys_only(data)
  array = []
  keys_only_iterate(data,array)
  array
end

def keys_only_iterate(data,array)
  return unless data.is_a?(Hash) || data.is_a?(Array)
  if data.is_a?(Hash)
    data.each do |k, v|
      array << k
      keys_only_iterate(v,array)
    end
  else
    data.each do |v|
      keys_only_iterate(v,array)
    end
  end
end

array = keys_only(x)
puts array
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def array_traverse(array, hash_keys)                                            
  2 array.each do |i|                                                               
  3 if i.class == Array                                                             
  4 hash_keys = array_traverse(i, hash_keys)                                        
  5 elsif i.class == Hash                                                           
  6 hash_keys = hash_traverse(i, hash_keys)                                         
  7 end                                                                             
  8 end                                                                             
  9 return hash_keys                                                                
 10 end                                                                             
 11 def hash_traverse(hash, hash_keys)                                              
 12 hash.keys().each do |i|                                                         
 13 if hash[i].class == Array                                                       
 14 hash_keys = array_traverse(hash[i], hash_keys)                                  
 15 elsif hash[i].class == Hash                                                     
 16 hash_keys = hash_traverse(hash[i], hash_keys)                                   
 17 end                                                                             
 18 hash_keys.push(i)                                                               
 19 end                                                                             
 20 return hash_keys                                                                
 21 end  
a={                                                                             
 24 "CourseID"=> 1111,                                                              
 25 "Course"=> {                                                                    
 26 "Code"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 27 "Name"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 28 "Qualification"=> "ABCD",                                                       
 29 "Discipline"=> "ABCD"                                                           
 30 },                                                                              
 31 "Modules"=> [                                                                   
 32 {                                                                               
 33 "ID"=> 12345,                                                                   
 34 "Code"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 35 "Name"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 36 "Core"=> true,                                                                  
 37 "Units"=> [                                                                     
 38 {                                                                               
 39 "ID"=> 23456,                                                                   
 40 "Code"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 41 "Name"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 42 "Core"=> true,                                                                  
 43 "my_key"=> true                                                                 
 44 },                                                                              
 45 {                                                                               
 46 "ID"=> 34567,                                                                   
 47 "Code"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 48 "Name"=> "ABCD",                                                                
 49 "Core"=> true,                                                                  
 50 "my_key"=> true                                                                 
 51 }                                                                               
 52 ]                                                                               
 53 }                                                                               
 54 ]                                                                               
 55 }                                                                                
 22 puts hash_traverse(a, [])
```